# Java Infix to Postfix method using queue and stack not working

Tags: java, stack, infix-notation

I'm trying to convert infix to postfix expressions in Java, but somehow it's not reading it in correctly or there might be something wrong with my queue implementation. I tried debugging but I can't see where I went wrong.

Inputs:

2 + 3

4 + 5+6

(7+8) * 9

Output:

2+

4+5

78

Correct outputs would be:

23+

45+6+

78+9*

This is my code:

```
public int Prior (char c) {

    if (c == '/' || c == '*')
        return 2;
    else if (c == '+' || c == '-')
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;

}

public String convertIn2Post() throws StackException, QueueException{

    infix = infix.trim();
    for(int i = 0; i < infix.length(); i++) {

        if(Character.isDigit(infix.charAt(i))) {

            expQueue.enqueue(infix.charAt(i) + "");

        }
        if (infix.charAt(i) == '(') {

            opStack.push(infix.charAt(i) + "");

        }
        if (infix.charAt(i) == ')') {

            while(opStack.peek().equals("(") != true) {

                expQueue.enqueue(opStack.pop());

            }
            opStack.pop();

        }
        if (        infix.charAt(i) == '+' || 
                    infix.charAt(i) == '-' ||
                    infix.charAt(i) == '/' ||
                    infix.charAt(i) == '*' ) {

            if(opStack.isEmpty()){
                opStack.push(infix.charAt(i) + "");
            }
            while(Prior(infix.charAt(i)) <= Prior(opStack.peek().charAt(0))){

                expQueue.enqueue(opStack.pop());

                if(opStack.isEmpty()){
                    break;
                }
            }

        }


    }

    while(!opStack.isEmpty()){
        expQueue.enqueue(opStack.pop());
    }

    for(int y = 0; y < expQueue.size(); y++){
        postfix += expQueue.dequeue();
    }


    return "postfix:: " + postfix;


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, one simple bug in the program is the loop that will dequeue everything.  Notice, that each time the loop is run, it checks that

```
 y < expQueue.size()
```

but, everytime an element is dequeued from the queue, this value is decreasing.  So, if the size starts at 6, the program will run for y = 0, size = 6, y = 1, size = 5, y = 2 size = 4, y = 3 size = 3 and that is where it stops.  So change this to a while loop:

```
while(!expQueue.isEmpty())
```

Next, the algorithm for converting infix to postfix says that if the opstack is empty, to push the operator, which is correct in the code.  Then it says that if it is not empty, if the one just found is of higher priority than the one on top of the stack, to add that one to the top of the stack, otherwise pop the top and add the new operator to the stack; this can be done as follows:

```
if(opStack.isEmpty()){
                opStack.push(infix.charAt(i) + "");
            }
            else
            {
                String peek = opStack.peek();
                if(Prior(peek.charAt(0)) >= Prior(infix.charAt(i)))
                {
                    expQueue.add(opStack.pop());
                    opStack.push(infix.charAt(i) + "");
                }
                else 
                {
                    opStack.push(infix.charAt(i) + "");
                }
            }
```